# cURL changing the URL after POST

Tags: php, post, curl, httpwebrequest

I am doing an HTTP POST using cURL

```
$url = "http://localhost:8080/~demo/cgi-bin/execute/100";

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($data));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo("$result");
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

The post gets executed, but the response is shown with the error:

> **The requested URL /~demo/100 was
>   not found on this server**.

---

The above URL, obviously, does not exist not the server because (somehow) cURL has changed the URL.

It should have been `/~demo/cgi-bin/execute/100` . This URL works in browser.

Please tell me why does it do that?
AND how can i stop this, for what I want?

Comment: presumably if you try to visit http://localhost:8080/~demo/cgi-bin/execute/100 in  a browser window it works?

Comment: throw a print_r( curl_getinfo($ch) ); after the curl_exec() to see what you got back.

Comment: Should be curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);

Answer (score 2):

- Install Fiddler.
- Enable debugging.
- Visit the site in the browser.
- Execute php cURL code.

Fiddler will tell you exactly what the web server is receiving and sending. since you are running locally, you can see exactly what php is sending as well. Compare the two and that will tell you the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe cURL tries to access default http port 80? Try to use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8080)
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be cURL that is changing the URL, rather that the web server is sending a redirect header to cURL, pointing at a different location.  Perhaps the following would help:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
```

Comment: Yes. http://localhost:8080/~demo/cgi-bin/execute/100 works in a browser. But this method doesn't requests it at al.

Answer (score 0):

where is?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```